# Como baixar um pdf no android

Tags: android

No meu app vai ter uma listView com os titulos de pdf, ao clicar queria baixar para o aparelho, uma forma de abrir offline, como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue abaixo um exemplo

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;

public class DownloadAsync extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    Context ctx;
    ProgressDialog loadingDialog;

    public DownloadAsync(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        loadingDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        loadingDialog.setTitle("Sistema");
        loadingDialog.setMessage("Baixando arquivo");
        loadingDialog.setCancelable(false);
        loadingDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        loadingDialog.setMax(100);
        loadingDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pdfs/";
        String SITE = "http://www.site.com.br";
        String arquivoNome = params[0];

        try{
            URL url = new URL(SITE + "/" + arquivoNome);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

            String FilePath = PATH + "/" + arquivoNome;

            File file = new File(PATH);
            file.mkdirs();

            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(FilePath);

            byte data[] = new byte[1024];
            long total = 0;
            int count;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                loadingDialog.setProgress((int)total * 100 / fileLength);
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();

            return FilePath;
        }
        catch(Exception e){ }

        return "";
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //RESULT CONTEM O CAMINHO LOCAL DO ARQUIVO
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Uso

```
new DownloadAsync(this).execute("meu_pdf.pdf");
```

Comment: Não tem como postar o codigo ja com a barra de progresso nao?

Comment: esse obj.getString, manda criar o obj

Comment: Perdão esqueci de alterar, ali você coloca o nome que vai ser salvo o pdf

Comment: tem o codigo completo com a barra de progresso?

Comment: e eu quero q ele seja o nome do proprio arquivo neh, nao quero alterar o nome

Comment: Alterei o código postado, confere ai... criei dentro de um AsyncTask :)

Comment: Creio que no onPostExecute se você passar a uri result pra Intent ele vai abrir o arquivo localmente :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20487/discussion-between-war-lock-and-milton-filho).

Comment: vai no bp pf...

Comment: nao ta funcionando, na hora de usar

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simple seria lanzar un intent do navegador con a url do document pdf

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(pdf_url));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: Não é isso que quero, quero que ao clicar na lista, ele baixe para o celular o pdf, e abra offline com o leitor do celular.

Comment: Não foi somente isto que ele perguntou.

Answer (score 0):

Não vou me prender a forma que você vai guardar esse pdf no seu dispositivo, pois imagino que você tenha um mínimo de conhecimento para, pelo menos, criar uma forma de por o título do documento em PDF nessa variável: `String tituloURIpdf;`, OU SEJA BAIXAR OU DEIXAR O ARQUIVO NA PRÓPRIA COMPILAÇÃO, que depende do objetivo. @Milton Filho, deu uma dica de como baixar, é uma das formas de se conseguir o título do arquivo. Essa variável estará na Atividade principal, **lembre-se dela**.

Começamos a codificar pela parte mais básica, o XML do ListView, o “main.xml”. Vamos definir nele somente um ListView e configurar algumas coisas, por exemplo: uma cor de fundo para nosso LinearLayout (android:background) a cor do divisor de itens do ListView (android:divider) sua espessura (android:dividerHeight) e um id (android:id).

**Listagem 1**: Código do main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
 > 

<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:divider="#FFECECEC" 
android:dividerHeight="2sp" 
/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Agora que temos nossa lista, precisamos dos itens, para isso vamos criar o XML responsável por eles, o “item_list.xml”. Em nosso item vamos inserir uma imagem e dois textos em uma linha horizontal. Um dos textos será a nossa URI, para poder baixar o pdf.

Foi inserido um LinearLayout horizontal (android:orientation) para nossa linha e dentro dela um ImageView responsável pela imagem e um TextView que terá seu texto centralizado verticalmente (android:gravity) com uma margem a esquerda para que não fique junto a imagem (android:layout_marginLeft).

**Listagem 2:** Código do item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:padding="5sp"> 

<ImageView 
android:id="@+id/imagemview" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/NOME_ICONE_DE_DOWNLOAD_NA_PASTA_drawable" /> 

<TextView 
android:id="@+id/text" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" 
android:gravity="center_vertical" 
android:textColor="#FF000000" /> 


<TextView 
android:id="@+id/URI" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5sp" 
android:gravity="center_vertical" 
android:textColor="#FF000000" /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

Toda a parte do layout já foi definida com esses dois arquivos, agora o próximo passo é criar nossa classe que vai popular os itens e o adaptador deixando por último a que vai controlar tudo isso.

**Classe 1:** MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    private String tituloURIpdf; //VARIÁVEL FALADA NO COMEÇO DA RESPOSTA
    private ListView listView;
    private AdapterListView adapterListView;
    private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //carrega o layout onde contem o ListView
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

 //CRIANDO UMA PASTA PARA ARMAZENAR OS PDF
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
         File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"/AppNOME/MeusPDF/");
            directory.mkdirs();

    }

        //Pega a referencia do ListView
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        //Define o Listener quando alguem clicar no item.
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        createListView();
    }

    private void createListView() {
        //Criamos nossa lista que preenchera o ListView
        //Está limitada em 4 itens, mas você pode implementar isso para mais itens
        //Criando um for, por exemplo, e ponde em array. ESTUDE!
        //Estou lhe dando o básico

        itens = new ArrayList<ItemListView>();

        //tituloURIpdfÉ A VARIÁVEL FALADA NO COMEÇO DA RESPOSTA
        //Poderíamos usar ela para não colocar os títulos dos PDF na "mão"
        //EXEMPLO, mas ela está vazia, pois você vai criar ainda alguma forma de por
        //textos nela, neh?
        /*
        ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Apostila Java", Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + tituloURIpdf);
        */


        ItemListView item1 = new ItemListView("Apostila Java", Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + "ApostilaJava.pdf");

        ItemListView item2 = new ItemListView("Desorientado por objeto", Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + "Desorientado.pdf");

        ItemListView item3 = new ItemListView("Revista -Por que votei na Dilma?", Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + "foraDilma.pdf");

        ItemListView item4 = new ItemListView("Stackoverflow bíblia", Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + "StackoverflowBible.pdf");

        itens.add(item1);
        itens.add(item2);
        itens.add(item3);
        itens.add(item4);

        //Cria o adapter
        adapterListView = new AdapterListView(this, itens);

        //Define o Adapter
        listView.setAdapter(adapterListView);
        //Cor quando a lista é selecionada para ralagem.
        listView.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

        //Aqui será onde o usuário irá baixar os seus PDF.
        //Lebrando que eu IMAGINO que você saiba como .
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        //Pega o item que foi selecionado.
        ItemListView item = adapterListView.getItem(arg2);

        Buscando caminho do arquivo
        Uri ArquivoPDF= Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/AppNOME/MeusPDF/" + item.getPdf() );

        //DOWNLOAD            
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setDataAndType(ArquivoPDF, "application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);

        //Demostração
        Toast.makeText(this, "Você baixou o arquivo : " + item.getPdf(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Criaremos nosso Objeto de acordo com nosso item através das funções da classe abaixo. 
Use sua imaginação pra criar as funções e retornar os valores. Brinque!

**Classe 2:** ItemListView.class

```
public class ItemListView {


    private String titulo;
    private String pdfUri;


    public ItemListView() {
    }

    public ItemListView(String titulo, String iconeRid) {
        this.pdfUri = pdfUri;
        this.iconeRid = iconeRid;
    }


    public String getTitulo() {
        return titulo;
    }

    public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
        this.titulo = titulo;
    }

    public String getPdfUri() {
        return pdfUri;
    }

    public void setPdfUri(String pdfUri) {
        this.pdfUri = pdfUri;
    }
}
```

Após criado o Objeto vamos criar o Adapter, o coração do ListView.

O getView() é nosso método principal, ele é o atualizador da lista, que é frequentemente atualizada e a cada vez, esse método é executado de acordo com a quantidade de itens do getCont(). Ele recebe 3 parâmetros: a posição, a view da atualização anterior que é nosso layout já carregado (desatualizado) e o ViewGroup que é (se houver) o “pai” da view.

Vamos criar uma classe interna chamada ItemSuporte que vai ter as views de nosso layout. Essa classe é criada para nos proporcionar uma rápida atualização para não que não seja preciso carregar todos os dados novamente. Se nossa view não existir, vamos inflá-la (carregar) através do atributo LayoutInflater que foi criado no construtor da classe. Após o layout ser carregado e atribuído à view, vamos criar o ItemSuporte inserindo as views do item_list em seu interior. Depois de inserido, definimo-lo como uma tag da view pelo método setTag(), pois se a view já existisse nós apenas carregaríamos o ItemSuporte pelo getTag().

Após carregar ou criar a view, adicionamos o ItemListView respectivo à posição da lista e atualizamos os dados da nossa view pelos dados do nosso item e no final do método retornamos a view com os dados atualizados.

**Veja como é simples:**

**Classe 3:** AdapterListView .class

```
public class AdapterListView extends BaseAdapter {
 
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ArrayList<ItemListView> itens;
 
    public AdapterListView(Context context, ArrayList<ItemListView> itens) {
        //Itens que preencheram o listview
        this.itens = itens;
        //responsavel por pegar o Layout do item.
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
 
    /**
     * Retorna a quantidade de itens
     *
     * @return
     */
    public int getCount() {
        return itens.size();
    }
 
    /**
     * Retorna o item de acordo com a posicao dele na tela.
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public ItemListView getItem(int position) {
        return itens.get(position);
    }
 
    /**
     * Sem implementação
     *
     * @param position
     * @return
     */
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
 
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        ItemSuporte itemHolder;
        //se a view estiver nula (nunca criada), inflamos o layout nela.
        if (view == null) {
            //infla o layout para podermos pegar as views
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
 
            //cria um item de suporte para não precisarmos sempre
            //inflar as mesmas informacoes
            itemHolder = new ItemSuporte();
            itemHolder.txtTitle = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
            itemHolder.txtURI = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.URI));
            //itemHolder.imgIcon = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagemview));
 
            //define os itens na view;
            view.setTag(itemHolder);
        } else {
            //se a view já existe pega os itens.
            itemHolder = (ItemSuporte) view.getTag();
        }
 
        //pega os dados da lista
        //e define os valores nos itens.
        ItemListView item = itens.get(position);
        itemHolder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitulo());
        itemHolder.txtURI.setText(item.getPdfUri());
        
        //Veja se isto torna invisível o texto da URI
        itemHolder.txtURI.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //itemHolder.imgIcon.setImageResource(item.getIconeRid());
 
        //retorna a view com as informações
        return view;
    }
 
    /**
     * Classe de suporte para os itens do layout.
     */
    private class ItemSuporte {
 
        //ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtURI;
    }
 
}
```

---

**PERMISSÃO:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**DÚVIDAS??**